# Using a MySQL class in Java web app servlets

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications

This is my first attempt at a Java web app with servlets (and Java itself).  I'm trying to create a MySQL class that will handle queries, connection, etc.  For whatever reason. I can get the connection but once I try to execute a query it gives a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I'm pretty certain that I'm making some kind of rookie mistake. but it's not clear to me what it is.

Here is the SQL class

```
package coreservlets;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.*;


public class DBInterface {
    private static Connection conn;
    private Statement statement;

    public static Connection Conn() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmwebapp";
        String user = "user";
        String pw = "password";

        try{
            //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
        //System.out.println(conn.getAutoCommit());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("MySQL Connection failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return conn;
    }

    public ResultSet Query(String query){
        try{
        statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println(rs);
        return rs;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("TestServlet.java SQL connection failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The class I'm trying to call it in

```
package internalLogic;
import coreservlets.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TheWork {
    private DBInterface conn;
    private String param;
    private ResultSet set;

    public TheWork(String p){
        try {
              conn = (DBInterface) DBInterface.Conn();
              param = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE index =" + p ;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("In TheWork ctor SQL connection or variable assignment failed.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }

    public String Execute(){
        set = conn.Query(param);
        System.out.println(set);
        Object s = null;
        String ret = "";
        try{
            while (set.next()) {
                // Make container class for SQL result sets.
                if(s instanceof String){
                    s = set.getObject("index");         
                }
                if (s instanceof Integer){
                    s = String.valueOf(s);
               }
                ret += s + ", ";
            }
            return ret;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In TheWork Execute SQL connection or variable assignment failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who wants to help me out.

```
Oct 29, 2013 9:51:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Test] in context with path [/test-app] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at internalLogic.TheWork.Execute(TheWork.java:26)
    at testPackage.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur? Post the full stack trace.

Comment: Where does your NPE occur ?

Comment: Just a sidenote: This part: `"SELECT * FROM test WHERE index =" + p ;` is really really bad thing. It makes your code vulnerable on SLQ injection attacks. Use prepared statement instead. Also, close your connection after CRUD operation is done.

Comment: I added the stack trace in.  I know that's really bad practice for SQL injection, but I'm just trying to get the queries to work as I'm just learning this stuff.

Comment: To save us from counting what is line 26?

Comment: set = conn.Query(param);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Execute()` method the instance `conn` is probably `null`.
I think that in your `TheWork` class:

```
private DBInterface conn;
```

should be

```
private Connection conn;
```

and in the constructor

```
conn = (DBInterface) DBInterface.Conn();
```

should be simply

```
conn = DBInterface.Conn();
```

**UPDATE:** (The suggested above corrections are not useful)

After your last comment, I have realized what is happening; the real problem is that you need to return an instance of `DBInterface` from your `Conn()` method.
If you take your original code and change just the method `Conn()` like I did below, it should fix the problem ...

```
public static DBInterface Conn() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cmwebapp";
    String user = "user";
    String pw = "password";
    DBInterface dbInterface = new DBInterface();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dbInterface.conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("MySQL Connection failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dbInterface;
}
```

Comment: I had it this way at one point.  If I do this, when I call conn.Query(param) in TheWork.  I get an error saying I should cast it to DBInterface. This removes the error, but when I got to run the app I get this error:   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection cannot be cast to coreservlets.DBInterface

Comment: @scallopboat I have updated my answer, hope this will fix your problem!

Comment: Sorry for the late check mark.  Thanks for all your help!